# How to Press a Button on a Different Process (nunit.exe)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nunit

I have recorded this macro that attaches to a process (nunit.exe) for me. Now I'd like to press a button (named "Run") on the window of the process I am attaching to, but how? I have recorded this macro:

```vb
Sub DebugNUnit()
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand6")
'need a short delay for nunit process to appear in process list:
Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

Try

    Dim dbg2 As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger

    Dim trans As EnvDTE80.Transport = dbg2.Transports.Item("Default")

    Dim dbgeng(1) As EnvDTE80.Engine

    dbgeng(0) = trans.Engines.Item("Managed (v4.0)")

    Dim proc2 As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, "myPC").Item("nunit.exe")

    proc2.Attach2(dbgeng)

Catch ex As System.Exception

    MsgBox(ex.Message)

End Try
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** I have adjusted the script based on the answer like this

```vb
Sub DebugNUnit()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand6")
    'need a short delay for nunit process to appear in process list:
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

    Try

        Dim dbg2 As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger

        Dim trans As EnvDTE80.Transport = dbg2.Transports.Item("Default")

        Dim dbgeng(1) As EnvDTE80.Engine

        dbgeng(0) = trans.Engines.Item("Managed (v4.0)")

        Dim proc2 As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, "myPC").Item("nunit.exe")

        proc2.Attach2(dbgeng)

        'added this because we may need a short delay for nunit gui to load
        '(would prefer to replace it with a wait on some loaded event or something)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

        'use Process.Handle or Process.MainWindowHandle? anyway, both do not seem to work.. are the parameters incorrect?
        Dim ButtonHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(proc2.ProcessID).Handle, 0, "Button", "Run")
        'Dim ButtonHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(proc2.ProcessID).MainWindowHandle, 0, "Button", "Run")

        SendMessage(ButtonHandle, &HF5, 0, 0)

    Catch ex As System.Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

but the "Run" button on the nunit user interface that was launched (by Tools.ExternalCommand6) still isn't being pressed. that makes sense because the button handle appears to be always 0.. why? is there anyone out there with a solution?

**UPDATE:** I have adjusted the script based on the edited answer like this

```vb
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module RecordingModule

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Function PostMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Sub DebugNUnit()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand6")
    'need a short delay for nunit processes to appear in process list:
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Try

        Dim dbg2 As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger
        Dim trans As EnvDTE80.Transport = dbg2.Transports.Item("Default")
        Dim dbgeng(1) As EnvDTE80.Engine
        dbgeng(0) = trans.Engines.Item("Managed (v4.0)")
        Dim proc2nunitagent As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, Environment.MachineName).Item("nunit-agent.exe")
        Dim proc2nunit As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, Environment.MachineName).Item("nunit.exe")
        proc2nunitagent.Attach2(dbgeng)

        PostMessage(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(proc2nunit.ProcessID).MainWindowHandle, &H100, Keys.Alt Or Keys.R, IntPtr.Zero)

    Catch ex As System.Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace)

    End Try

End Sub
End Module
```

I am using nunit 2.5.7 and for attaching and debugging to work you need to attach to the nunit agent and press run on the nunit gui, for more recent versions of nunit you can attach to the nunit gui.

the above script enables nunit debugging from the Visual Studio IDE with just visual Studio and the nunit binaries. all you need to do is set up nunit as an external tool (with the current project as a parameter), create a custom toolbar, and add a button to that toolbar that uses the above script. this will start nunit, attach to it, start running the tests, and break at your breakpoint.

one more thing: in the nunit gui disable "Save Visual state of each Project" in Tools -> Settings -> Tree Display or the nunit gui will remember the last run test, which is a pain if that's not the one you wanted to debug.

possible improvements: build before starting nunit.

Comment: If you're merely looking to debug your unit tests, I suggest you get something like TestDriven.NET or ReSharper. They both allow you to easily debug your tests from within Visual Studio.

Comment: I am familiar with those tools but they are not freeware, and freeware tools like VisualNUnit are not reliable enough. and besides, I'm nearly there.. all I need now is the button handle and I have my own custom toolbar with a button that launches NUnit for the current project, attaches to it, runs the tests, and breaks on my breakpoint.

Comment: Visual NUnit is open source, as opposed to freeware; you could always fix it...?

Comment: I have a feeling that's more work than a bit of VB script so I want to try this approach first, and I quite like the fact that this approach doesn't require another extension

Comment: Or you could just set nunit-console.exe as the process to be debugged...

Comment: true, but the nunit gui may be a bit more pleasant to watch (red/green bars) and use. besides, the nunit console starts testing right away and it has no delay option so that would require some fiddling to attach to before the test is run.

Comment: If you set it as the process to be debugged, it's already attached. Or am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6788/discussion-between-mtijn-and-roger-lipscombe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Dim ButtonHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(YOURPROCESS.HANDLE, 0, "Button", "&Run")
SendMessage(ButtonHandle, &HF5, 0, 0)
```

**EDIT** : Seems like NUint is a .NET app which means you can't get the button handle easily. You can see that for yourself with the help of Spy++.

I noticed that the button `Run` has a keyboard shortcut of `ALT + R` so instead you can use this code:

```vb
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
PostMessage(MAIN_WINDOW_HANDLE, &H100, Keys.Alt Or Keys.R, IntPtr.Zero)
```

I tested this and it works fine.

Comment: that's totally awesome, thanks! but now how do I get the process handle for nunit.exe? I already have the EnvDTE80.Process2 object for it but that doesn't seem to be of any use..

Comment: nunit.exe is the process of the NUnit GUI. see my question, I have updated it with the latest results.

Comment: thanks exactly what I needed, I have posted the end result in the question.